# How can i fix this problem with json.parse?

Tags: angular, angular7

i have a problem a parsing method. I do a call to a WebService and in Angular i made a post request.
The returning object is right but when i do a `JSON.parse()` it not work good because as u can see on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qTTk.jpg) some value vanish when i parse the result. Why it happen? How can i fix it?

In my call i do this :

```
 this.ts.getGiorni(user).subscribe((res => {
  console.log(res);
  this.timeSheet = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
  console.log(this.timeSheet);
```

..more code

The result is this : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qTTk.jpg

EDIT :

**Why are you stringifying and then parsing it again?
Because i have a copy of this response and if i do: this.timesheet = res; and this.copyOfTimesheet = res; when i modify the copy the main timesheet will be modify too because they have the same allocation of memory**

Comment: Why are you stringifying and then parsing it again?

Comment: Because i have a copy of this response and if i do: this.timesheet = res; and this.copyOfTimesheet = res; when i modify the copy the main timesheet will be modify too because they have the same allocation of memory

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. In general, stringify+parse will cause a loss of information: functions, prototype properties and basically anything that can not be converted to string. `uscitaPM` doesn't look like it should go missing. Are you sure those screenshots are from that code exactly?

Comment: Yes. I try more solution but nothing work. I think i need another aproach or another method to do this but i dont know what is the alternative for do this

Comment: Could you separate the `stringify()` and the `parse()` calls, and show the output of just `stringify()`?

Comment: Its the same. Nothing change

Comment: I didn't mean that it would change, I just think the output from `stringify()` could be useful to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your res does not contain nested object (as shown in the screenshot) you can use `Object.assign()`.

`this.timeSheet = Object.assign({}, res);`

Comment: Try to use `cloneDeep` from lodash https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep. You will have to include this library to work.